# the value of <option> is array

Tags: php

Im just thinking if this possible

this is the code of the ....

```
    <?php
    $temp1 = 'anyvalue1';
    $temp2 = 'anyvalue2';
    ?>
<form action='next.php' method='post'>
    <select name='dropdown'>
    <option value='any'>item1</option>
    <option value='anyone'>item2</option>
    <option value='<? $dual = array("$temp1","temp2"); ?>'>item3</option>
    </select>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

as you can see at the top did the `item3` lines of code is possible? then later i use that , in this sql code(this sql code is only below at the code above)

```
$keyword = $_POST['dropdown'];
$res = mysql_query("select * from teybol where field1='$keyword[0]' and field2='keyword[1]'");
```

then later generate the record by the result of `$res`

Answer (score 0):

Values of HTML `option`s are always strings when interpreted by Javascript or PHP. You could, however, format it in such a way that you could translate it into an array later:

```
<option value='["$temp1","$temp2"]'>item3</option>
```

or

```
<option value='{"$temp1","$temp2"}'>item3</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in that way. You have to find a string representation of your "dual" option:

```
<option value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars("$temp1-$temp2") ?>'>item 3</option>
```

*This assumes a dash is not present in either `$temp1` or `$temp2`*

Then when you query:

```
$keywords = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', explode('-', $_POST['dropdown']));
$sql = "select * from teybol where field1='$keywords[0]'";
if (count($keywords) > 1) {
    $sql .= " and field2='keywords[1]'";
}
// use $sql to perform the query
```

You can also use JSON format - using `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` - for the string representation; it helps in cases whereby a delimiter such as `-` can't be used reliably.

**Note** You should escape variables that you're using in SQL; I'm doing that here by using `array_map()` to apply `mysql_real_escape_string` on each keyword.

**Note 2** You should move to either PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements instead.